# Check if all the elements in that list are divisible by some given integer or not

Tags: python

Given a list, I wanted to check if all the elements in that list are divisible by some given integer or not. Based on that, i have to return a boolean value.

```
l=[10,30,40,20]
```

For example - all the elements of this list are divisible by 5. Then, I would return `True`.
For 6, I would have returned `False`.

One approach I could think of is to generate an array consisting off boolean values and then `AND` them.

```
blist=[x%5==0 for x in l]
# [False, False, False, False]
# AND THE ELEMENTS
```

But this approach kind of feels bad. Can anyone suggest a more simple `pythonic` way out of this.

Comment: Don't you mean `x % 5 == 0` not `x / 5 == 0`?

Comment: Yups.. Thanks. I will correct it right away ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you want modulo division (`%`) as you want to see if it evenly divides by `5`, so you are checking for a remainder, not the result of division.

You can use [the `all()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) (which does what it says on the tin), but [you don't need to generate a list, instead use a generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
all(x%5 == 0 for x in l)
```

This has the advantage of being lazy, so as soon as a value isn't divisible it will return, saving computation

Answer (score 4):

Using list comprehensions is pythonic.  And you need to use mod not div.

Use `all` built in

```
res = all([x%5==0 for x in l])
```

You can do this more efficiently by

```
res = all(x%5 == 0 for x in l)
```

which uses a generator expression.  In the first case python generates a list of all the mod values, in the second case the values are generated as they are needed by `all` and are hence only generated up to the first non-divisible value.

Comment: Get rid of the `blist=` and the brackets around the list comprehension.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 2, in <module>
    res = all(blist=[x/5==0 for x in l])
TypeError: all() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: You mean `res = all([x/5==0 for x in l])` ??

Comment: You also don't need the brackets: `all(x%5==0 for x in l)`